# HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject very slow for fallback culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web site project with two .resx files in the App_GlobalResources folder:

```
Texts.resx
Texts.de.resx
```

If I request a resource string with the culture "de-DE" the response time is around 0.01 ms. If I request the same resource string with a culture that is not directly available (e.g. "en-US" or "jp-JP") the response time increases by a factor of 1000. However, it produces the correct result (from the neutral resource file).

The call is:

```
string result = (string) HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Texts",
    "MyString", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

The environment is Windows 7 (German) x64 with .NET Framework 4.0. I can reproduce this on Windows Server 2008 R2, too.

Can anyone explain this? Is there a workaround to access the fallback resource faster?

Could it be related to [this Microsoft Connect ticket](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/505393/net-framework-4-beta-2-resourcemanager-new-fallback-bug-or-fix)?